# Can I rely on a simple gas valve to shut off the gas?

Tags: pipe, gas, valve, remodeling, natural-gas

I have a gas pipe with a simple turn shut-off valve in line on the pipe feeding the section I need to work on. Is shutting it off there sufficient enough to do the work I need to do, or do I need to shut it off at the main?

Scenario;
We recently found the foundation had bowed in just a little which put pressure on where this piece of pipe angles to feed a fireplace and the laundry room for a gas dryer. I had dead man anchors etc installed to take care of the foundation issue. Now I need to replace two pipes to take off any pressure from the pipeline.

See in the image, the foundation is pressed up against and even bending the pipe;
[image]

So I need to replace both pipes feeding this corner. Conveniently after breaking down  more ceiling (amazing what you find when you remodel) I found this in-line valve I turned off that feeds this section.
[image]

Can I get away with just having that in-line valve shut-off to do what I need to do? I've never done it without the main shut-off but there's like 4 neighbors gas registers in my yard and I don't know which is mine, but I still wanted to be safe and get some opinions first. Advice welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should do the trick for a start. You will smell gas when you disassemble the pipe and should dissipate. On the jobsite, when this is done, the longer pipe section is removed from the valve on the fed side (fireplace side) of the pipe and capped with a threaded plug with the proper tape sealant or pipe dope approved for gas fittings. A nipple and cap can be used too, instead of a plug. Its a variation of the same thing.

Do be careful on this, this should go without saying, you are dealing with some really explosive stuff here.

Comment: I'm thinking I need to replace the pipe from the valve to the junction, and the pipe that goes down to the fireplace since it's been bent by this. Do you think I can rely on that valve to keep the gas out of the line while I do that? Or would it be smart to go ahead and find out which gas register is mine and just shut it off at the main first?

Comment: It is almost elementary, but if you need to replace a line on the pressure side of the valve, you will certainly need to shut down the main. If the main is in your yard and not part of a utility easement, shut the main anyway, though you may not need to shut it to replace the pipe on the fireplace side only. The junction you mention is elusive to me, I do not know where it is in respect of the picture, I see an elbow and maybe a tee only... Yes it should keep the gas out, but always cap the pipe whenever possible while the work is going in.